# remove number from a column in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having a column as below in excel. Consider it as a column of elements.

excel_data:

| Animal |
| --- |
| Dog12ag |
| Cat13 |
| Choco1234ttt |

I need to remove from number in excel.

Desired output:-

| Animal |
| --- |
| Dog |
| Cat |
| Choco |

Is there any formula for doing it?

Comment: What version do you have?

Comment: Microsoft 365 is my version

Answer (score 4):

Try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=@TEXTSPLIT(A1,SEQUENCE(10,,0))
```

Or, in a single go:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=TEXTSPLIT(A1:A4,SEQUENCE(10,,0))
```

Thanks to @Ike.

Comment: `=TEXTSPLIT(A1:A4,SEQUENCE(10,,0))` spills down as well

Comment: To be honest: I don't understand why it works like this. I would have expected that everything spills to the right as well. Is this due to the fact that that would result in different number of columns per row?

Comment: @Ike my brain thought the same hence I didn't try at first but I did notice this behaviour with `TEXTSPLIT()` before where when used on an array it will spill only every 1st element in the resulting array. I have created a ticked for that a while back too. Other functions like `EXPAND()` or `WRAPROWS()` and `WRAPCOLS()` have a special parameter to counter possible empty values/errors hence I don't understand why they "forgot" this parameter with `TEXTSPLIT()`.

Comment: TEXTSPLIT is not the only one that does this.  You can acheive the same with filterxml.  Any time one tries to spill in both directions using a formula that creates an array in one direction, only the first is brought in.  I have been successful in using BYROW and BYCOLUMN in a MAKEARRAY at times to overcome this.  But I agree, that this is something that should be "fixed".

Answer (score 2):

The following will spill the results:

```
=BYROW(A1:A4,LAMBDA(b,LEFT(b,MIN(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},b&"1234567890")-1))))
```

[image]

Comment: In the meantime it is available to Current Channel as well :-): https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel-blog/what-s-new-in-excel-august-2022/ba-p/3590457

Comment: @Ike then they need to update the site, as it still says insider beta only.

Comment: @Scott Craner, actually each of the word is seperate column. Like Animal is one column value,Dog12ag is another value. I need to remove from the letters from number. Like Dog12ag to Dog.Is that possible?

Comment: I am sorry..its my first time

Comment: @NikitaMenon see edit

Answer (score 1):

You may try this as well,

[image]

• Formula used in cell `B1`,

```
=LET(x,MIN(IFERROR(SEARCH(ROW($1:$10)-1,A1),"")),
IF(x<>0,REPLACE(A1,x,255,""),
A1))
```

---

Edit: Using `TEXTBEFORE()`

[image]

```
=TEXTBEFORE(A1,SEQUENCE(10,,0),,,1,A1)
```

Or,

```
=TEXTBEFORE(A1:A4,SEQUENCE(10,,0),,,1,A1:A4)
```