# In Excel 365, how can I get unique counts of a multi-column array?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I would like to write a function that takes as input an `array` with `m` rows and `n` columns and outputs an array of `q` rows and `n+1` columns, where `q` is the number of unique row-wise combinations in the input `array`, and the additional column is integers representing the count of each unique combination. Example image:

[image: target input/output]

**My attempted solution is:**

```
UNIQUECOUNT = LAMBDA(array,
    LET(
        u, UNIQUE(array),
        aj, BYROW(array,
            LAMBDA(row, TEXTJOIN("\", FALSE, row))),
        uj, BYROW(u, LAMBDA(row, TEXTJOIN("\", FALSE, row))),
        c, COUNTIF(aj, uj),
        HSTACK(u, c)
    )
);
```

**Where:**

`u` is each unique row (`q`×`n`)

`aj` is a 'joined' version of the input array (`m`×`1`)

`uj` is the 'joined' version of each unique row (`q`×`1`)

`c` is the count of each unique row (`q`×`1`)

Assume I have guaranteed that "" does not exist in any of my data.

**The problem:**

This formula returns an `m`×`1` array of `#VALUE!` errors. However, if these steps are broken into multiple cells that refer to the previous step by spilled cell address (ex. `D2#`), the result works as expected.

[image: working cell by cell]

In my mind, this means there's some kind of 'type' error going on, where the function works when given a range but not an array?

**Minimal example:**

With this in mind, I tried to set up a minimal test to replicate the problem. In this example, I'm only trying to show the counts of an input array with a single column. I have written 4 different ways of defining `a` which should perform the same, but do not:

```
TEST = LAMBDA(array,
    LET(
        a, array,
        // a, BYROW(array, LAMBDA(row, row)),
        // a, MAP(array, LAMBDA(val, val)),
        // a, REDUCEMAP(array, LAMBDA(val, val)),

        u, UNIQUE(a),
        COUNTIF(a, u)
    )
);
```

1. Base case, performs as expected
2. Similar to but simpler than my original function, gives `m`×`1` `#VALUE!` errors
3. Inspired by [answers on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74400507/8305404), I tried to use `MAP` instead of `BYROW`, but the same errors occur
4. Following [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73853318/8305404), I wrote a wrapper around `REDUCE` to make it function like `MAP` by using `VSTACK`, but the same errors occur

(function below for reference)

```
REDUCEMAP = LAMBDA(array, func,
    DROP(
        REDUCE(0, array, LAMBDA(acc, next, VSTACK(acc, func(next)))), 1
    )
);
```

[Other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75071449/8305404) suggested that the implicit intersection operator `@` can resolve issues, but I've had no luck changing any of the above behavior using it.

So, my practical question is: How can I write a LAMBDA function that fits the description given at the top of the post?

And my theoretical question is: How can I understand why my logic above works when performed cell-by-cell but not when put into LET variables? Is `range` vs `array` a useful distinction, and if so are there ways to mitigate these `array` problems without needing to dump them into a cell to turn into a `range`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution will ALWAYS deliver an n+1 column solution:

```
=LET(
    d, A2:B9,
    ad, BYROW(d, LAMBDA(b, CONCAT(b))),
    ud, UNIQUE(d),
    uad, UNIQUE(ad),
    HSTACK(ud, MAP(uad, LAMBDA(m, COUNTA(FILTER(ad, m = ad)))))
)
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to use the fewest 'tricks' to accomplish the goal, making it the most readable solution for me.

Comment: Filter with COUNTA wrapped around it is the way to go. Just need the MAP function to iterate dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

The reason it didn't work is that COUNTIF works with range inputs and inside LET-calculation it becomes an array.

MMULT is a good alternative to that:

```
=LET(input, A2:B9,
     seq,   SEQUENCE(ROWS(input)),
     join,  MAP(seq,LAMBDA(rw,TEXTJOIN("|",,INDEX(input,rw,)))),
     unq,   UNIQUE(join),
HSTACK(UNIQUE(input),
       MMULT(N(TOROW(join)=unq),seq^0)))
```

And because I want to get familiar with Python for Excel (for Beta insiders only) I managed to get the following:

```
=PY(
    df = pd.DataFrame (xl("A2:B9", headers=False))
    df["count"] = df.groupby(list(df.columns))[0].transform("count")
    df = df.drop_duplicates()
    df = df.values.tolist()
)
```

[image]

Comment: Heads-up: The idea is to create an n+1 situation, where input can be more than just two columns though. The +1 is simply a stack of input of n-columns and the count of each unique row.

Comment: @JvdV Thanks for the heads-up. That's me thinking I'd post an answer right before going to bed. I recognized the problem (COUNTIF taking a range, not an array), and saw the formula + example, but not the (good) explanation of the intent. See my edit to deal with it correctly.

Comment: Great! Now do this in Python =)

Comment: Lol! get more more experienced there.

Comment: I already applied one of @JvdV Sirs solution using `Python` and Regex i think, worked so fast, unimaginable!

Comment: @jvdV I Managed to get a working solution in Python.

Comment: For python, check out [df.value_counts()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html)

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame (xl("A2:B9"))
df = df.value_counts(sort=False).rename("count").reset_index()
df = df.values.tolist()` but that's not listing the order as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I think the following might work:

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=UNIQUECOUNT(A1:B8)
```

Where `UNIQUECOUNT()` refers to:

```
=LAMBDA(array,LET(u,UNIQUE(array),HSTACK(u,BYROW(u,LAMBDA(r,SUM(N(MMULT(--(array=r),SEQUENCE(COUNTA(r))^0)=COUNTA(r))))))))
```

So here we have a variable 'u' that is the condensed version of 'array' holding only it's unique rows. We use `BYROW()` to iterate over this condensed version. The idea then is that `MMULT()` is used to sum an array of boolean values when the unique row is matched against the entire 'array'. This sum happens to get row totals. See this [link](https://exceljet.net/formulas/get-row-totals) and scroll down to see some more explanation on how that works. The last step is simply to check if the sum was equal to the amount of values in the current unique row and do a final sum to be returned.

Comment: The result looks great, and I like that it doesn't depend on a join character. Can you share any explanation/thought process?

Comment: Aha, I was wondering if why to use exponentiation instead of `SEQUENCE(x, , , 0)` or `MAKEARRAY(x, , LAMBDA(x, y, 1))`, I suppose it's a readability vs character count tradeoff.

Answer (score 0):

Some further searching has turned up [this article](https://exceljet.net/articles/excels-racon-functions) that demonstrates issues with these so-called RACON functions (of which COUNTIF is one). Importantly, it appears that [these functions cannot accept arrays, only ranges](https://exceljet.net/articles/excels-racon-functions#range_required).

With this in mind, I re-wrote my function to avoid use of COUNTIF and instead use the double-negative SUM trick shown in the article.

```
UNIQUECOUNT = LAMBDA(array,
    LET(
        uniques, UNIQUE(array),
        aj, BYROW(array, LAMBDA(row, TEXTJOIN("\", FALSE, row))),
        uj, BYROW(uniques, LAMBDA(row, TEXTJOIN("\", FALSE, row))),
        matrix, MAKEARRAY(
            COUNTA(uj),
            COUNTA(aj),
            LAMBDA(row, col, --(CHOOSEROWS(uj, row) = CHOOSEROWS(aj, col)))
        ),
        counts, BYROW(matrix, LAMBDA(row, SUM(row))),
        HSTACK(uniques, counts)
    )
);
```

This could probably be more elegant, but the general idea is to construct a matrix (`q`×`m`) of booleans where each row is a unique value, and each column is an input from the raw array. Then the matrix is condensed by summing over the rows to get the final counts.